# Received PDF “scan” of alleged e-mail with Sent time later than Received? Fake?

Tags: email, pdf, time, date

I recently received a bulk PDF file version of important legal documents / correspondence etc. required for court case. I've found a number of suspicious looking, possibly altered docs, etc. After a closer look at a few pages of supposed e-mail correspondence, I noticed that the sent time was later than the received time. Does this mean it is fake e-mail? How do I tell?

Comment: *"I noticed that the sent time was later than the received time."* - This could be (potentially) explained by a difference in time zones or simply an incorrect system time (client or server).